# ubuntu messes up text after suspension

Tags: 14.04, suspend

My ubuntu after suspension completely messes up all text in the system. When I wake up my PC this is how my nautilus looks like

[image: wtf]

And sometimes after suspension it even logs out from my account. I started to experience it about 1-2 months ago and I didn't install anything suspicious. My system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux PC_NAME 4.4.0-38-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 17:20:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does it work fine after logging out and in?

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam it does

Comment: I'll try to look for a solution.

Comment: Try this temporary solution 1.CTRL+ALT+F1 then, 2.CTRL+ALT+F7. Does it work?

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam seems like it fixed problem with nautilus, but in all over places (like ubuntu menu on the top-right corner) text is still messed up. Also funny thing that my tty1 (`ctrl + alt + f1`) does not show anything. It's just a black screen

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam also it only solved problem in a current opened nautilus window if I open another the problem remains.

Comment: what about tty2 and others? I'll have to go offline now. I'lllook into the problem tommorow. Post(or Answer) if you find anything (or the solution). I'll keep searching for the solution till then.

Comment: If tty2 doesn't show anything post it as seperate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46430/discussion-between-emad-arshad-alam-and-dima).